# ng-change is not working with ngTagInput

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new in angular js .Here I am trying to call getTagsName function when user starts writing into the textbox.According to the keyword ,autocomplete suggestion will appear.But in my case ng-change is not working it seems ...Can anyone help me out..

my html:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags2" display-property="name" ng-change="getTagsNames()">
  <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

my js:

```
$scope.getTagNames = function() {
     $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
         return $http.get('tags.json');
     };
};
```

Comment: ng-change="getTagsNames()" and in js $scope.getTagNames . letter "s"(getTagNames ) is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ng-change() directive will not work because onChange() functionality will never be executed when the tags model changes on ngTagInput .

use
     `on-tag-added="getTagNames()"`  and `on-tag-removed="getTagNames()"`

```
 <tags-input ng-model="tags2" display-property="name" on-tag-added="getTagNames()" on-tag-removed="getTagNames()" >
```

Or u can watch the changes with `$scope.$watch` , as the tags are  arrays or objects `$scope.$watchCollection` can be used

```
 $scope.$watchCollection('tags2',function(){
    //execute the code on the changes

});
```

refer : http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api

Comment: hey when I am getting data in ng-model ,i am displaying it on page like {{tags}} and when  i am doing this data is displaying like :  [{"tagId":"2","tagName":"Tag2"}] (according to selected data),but when i am displaying like : {{tags.tagId}},its not working,i mean nothing is displaying.

Comment: @AshishSinha its objects collection in array i think you have use ng-repeat for displaying data or u should be using like this {{tags[0].tagId}}(first array object )

Comment: @AshishSinha  as im unaware of the data format , and as  mentioned above u have use ng-repeat for that which loops through them   ng-repeat="id in tagList.idtrack by track(id)",